# Wordpress the_custom_logo doesn't link on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using twentytwentyone-child theme and I want to link the custom_logo to the homepage even on the homepage.

But I can't find any setting for that?

I read this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_logo/

And it says: "Displays a custom logo, linked to home **unless the theme supports removing the link on the home page.**"

But if I look into the site-branding.php of the parent-theme I can only find this:

```php
<?php if ( has_custom_logo() && $show_title ) : ?>
    <div class="site-logo"><?php the_custom_logo(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="site-branding">

<?php if ( has_custom_logo() && ! $show_title ) : ?>
    <div class="site-logo"><?php the_custom_logo(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There is no if/else for linking it or don't link it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to add theme support for a custom logo?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani what do you mean by that? I have no site-branding.php in my child theme, so it uses the parent one. and there is no "link" in the source, it's just plain call on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of this code in the parent theme's functions.php:

```
add_theme_support(
    'custom-logo',
    array(
        'height'               => $logo_height,
        'width'                => $logo_width,
        'flex-width'           => true,
        'flex-height'          => true,
        'unlink-homepage-logo' => true,
    )
);
```

In your child theme's functions.php, you can remove the theme support, and then add it back again, which you can do with this:

```
remove_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );

$logo_width  = 300;
$logo_height = 100;

add_theme_support(
    'custom-logo',
    array(
        'height'               => $logo_height,
        'width'                => $logo_width,
        'flex-width'           => true,
        'flex-height'          => true,
        'unlink-homepage-logo' => false,
    )
);
```

**UPDATE**: You'll have to add this code to an action rather than using it directly in `functions.php`.

Comment: but it DOES link currently. On every page except the homepage.

But I want that link on the homepage as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction, I misunderstood. It's because TwentyTwentyOne adds theme support for removing the custom logo link on the home page. Let me see how to fix that.

Comment: OK, this should fix the problem for you.

Comment: thats exactly what I'm looking for but it's still not working :D.

I added it to the functions.php exactly as you've written it, but logo is still not linked on homepage

Comment: Had to pack it into an add_action then it worked! thanks!